# Plesk 9.5 API documentation confusion

Tags: documentation, plesk

I'm using Plesk 9.5.

I've read the [API overview for Plesk 9.5](http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PPP9/Doc/en-US/plesk-9.5-api-rpc-guide/), but that really is just an overview and a few sample bits. It doesn't have a full breakdown of all the XML tags and their meanings. I can find such a reference for [Plesk 10 (API 1.6.3.1)](http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP10/10.1.1/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-api-rpc/index.htm), but not for Plesk 9.5.

And there are some differences. For example, the Plesk 9.5 overview shows a sample of how to create a client. But the list of "Supported Operations" in the API 1.6.3.1 reference says nothing about clients. It does mention customers. What's the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plesk 9.5 uses api-rpc protocol 1.6.0.2 and works with clients. In plesk 10.x clients were renamed in customers and appropriate changes were made in api-rpc. So, in plesk9.5 you can use packet like this: 
`<packet version="1.6.0.2"><client><add> ... </add></client></packet>`
in plesk 10.x you can create "same" entity with operator:

`<packet version="1.6.3.0"><customer><add> ... </add></customer></packet>`.

Also changes were made in `domain` operator that was changes to `webspace`.

Comment: I assume documentation for 1.6.0.2 exists somewhere. Any suggestions where I could find it?

Comment: plesk api has got very poor documentation, actually you can use xsd schemas(http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PPP9/Doc/en-US/plesk-9.5-api-rpc/) or official guides: http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PPP9/Doc/en-US/plesk-9.5-api-rpc.zip and http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PPP9/Doc/en-US/plesk-9.5-api-rpc-guide.pdf .

Comment: additional, most of plesk documentation is here: http://www.parallels.com/ptn/documentation/ppp/